# Examine C structure in Visual C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, data-structures, struct

I'm using a structure within a structure like this in VS2010 (simplified:)

```
struct s_ptx
{
    char xyz[33];
    int newCount;
} ptx;

struct s_stream
{
    struct ptx[20];
    int count;
} Stream[20];
```

Everything is hunky dory until I try to examine this structure in the debugger:
eg, if I try to "watch" Stream[0].ptx[3].xyz, it gives some cryptic message ("CXX0058 Error: overloaded operator not found.")

I did a lot of searching on the Web, and found this is not an uncommon problem, and that
the only way to examine these sorts of structures is through adding a complex bit of
code to the autoexp.dat file.

It would be one thing if it were C code that the autoexp.dat file required but, alas, it is something else, and it would be very time-consuming to learn this new language just to do what I want to do.

So, my question:

- does anyone know of a way to examine these sorts of structs in the VS debugger natively
- does anyone know of some code that I could copy into my autoexp.dat to do the job
- is anyone interested in writing this code as a service to me and all of mankind?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct s_stream
{
    struct ptx[20];  // **what is this ???**
    int count;
} Stream[20];
```

i think 2nd structure should be like this

```
struct s_stream
{
    struct s_ptx  temp[20];
    int count;
} Stream[20];
```

this code workd fine in my gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct s_ptx
{
    char xyz[33];
    int newCount;
} ptx;

struct s_stream
{
    struct s_ptx  temp[20];
    int count;
} Stream[20];

main()
{
 printf("this works fine %s",Stream[0].temp[3].xyz);


}
```

Comment: I think he nailed it down, you are creating an anonymous variable in your second struct. Just give it a name and you should be fine.

Comment: Your example was fine before. My answer was meant @OP.

Comment: i am not getting what you are saying

Comment: Sorry guys for error.  In trying to simplify things I inadvertently neglected to specify : struct s_ptx...    So the real code already works... What I'm trying to do is figure out how to add a "watch" in VS to examine the contents.   AFAIK, no native way to examine this in VS, and the alternative is learning/writing template to do so in the autoexp.dat file.  Anybody know of a way to do this natively in VS, or know of a template for an entry in the autoexp.dat file to examine a structure like this.  Many thanks.